# How to print all tags by using taggit?

Tags: django, tags

I have a small problem, namely I would like to be able to print all taggit tags in my Django project, but I can't seem to be able to make it work. Here's what I came up with until now:

views.py

```
from taggit.models import Tag
tags_all = Tag.objects.all()
```

and then I'm returning tags_all by using the return function. Then I add the following into my template:

```
{{ tags_all }}
```

However, the result I'm getting after rendering the template looks as follows:

```
<QuerySet [<Tag: security>, <Tag: Internet>]>
```

I would like to be able to get just tags, without the QuerySet bits. How can I achieve this? Just to remind you, I would like to be able to obtain all tags within the project. I have tried using taggit-templatetags and taggit-templatetags2, but they don't see to work properly with Django 2+.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better look can be achieved that way:

```
{% for tag in tags_all %}
     {{ tag }} {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% empty %}
     No tags
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you Lemayzeur for this piece of code. It does what I need it to do and also makes the tags look nicely arranged.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over queryset using [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle):

```
{% for tag in tags_all %}
    {{ tag.name }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Also since each tag is object, you can access tag's attribute with `.`, for example `tag.name`.

Comment: Thank you Neverwalkaloner for this code. I have marked your answer as useful, but the one below was the one that was I looking for, because it is arranging tags nicely by using the comma separator. Have a nice day.